# How to change the frame rate of a SWF file using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, swfloader

I have a flex application which loads the swf files using SWFLoader and i have set the frame rate of the application 60.When i load a swf file it is playing vary fast,I think this is happening for the application frame rate.I want the frame rate of application to be 60 and the swf which i have loaded must be at lower frame rate. Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible in a general sense, but you can play a `MovieClip` at any arbitrary frame-rate if you run the frames yourself, for example using a `Timer` with  `gotoAndStop` and possibly `updateAfterEvent`. I've written an extended timeline class to do just this in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible, there can be only one framerate at all time for the whole app and any loaded swf will use that same framerate. You can change the framerate for playing those swf and restore the normal framerate when done or you can create a class that will play those swf in time based framerate.